# Two related matrices with same Hilbert Schmidt norm

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-norms

> We have $BGx$ where $B$ is a fixed m×N matrix, and $G$ is an N×n
> (random) matrix, $x$ is a fixed vector in $R^n$. 
> By concatenating the rows of $G$ , we can view $G$ as a long vector in
> $R^{Nn}$.
> Consider the linear operator $T$ defined as  $T(G) =BGx$ . 
> Then,
> Hilbert-Schmidt norm of T equals $||B||_{HS}$
> with  $||B||^{2}_{HS}$ := $\sum_{i,j} b_{ij}^{2}$

I have tried to write out the identity given by the operator $T$ but I can't quite compare the non $g_{ij}$ term in the resulting vector, i.e. the i_th component of the vectors are as followed

$\sum_{p=1}^{Nn}t_{ip}g'_{p}=\sum_{j=1}^{N}b_{ij}\sum_{k=1}^{n}g_{jk}x_{k}$

with $g'_{p}$ correspond to the j-th component of $G$'s long vector form.

How can I show their HS norm is the same?

*In case my presentation is not clear above, see below for the original content. [image]

Comment: We need more information about $x$. First of all, it seems as thought $x$ is a fixed vector; please explicitly state whether this is the case. Second, if $x$ is allowed to be **any** vector, then the result fails to hold. For example, if $x = 0$ and $B \neq 0$, then clearly the norm of $T$ is zero but $\|B\|_{HS}$ is not.

Comment: @BenGrossmann thanks for pointing that out, I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see $G$ as a [long vector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)) in $R^{Nn}$.

You can use [Kronecker product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product#Matrix_equations) to see the linear operator $T$, defined as  $T(G) =BGx$, as $$(x^T\otimes B)vec(G)=[x_1B\,\,x_2B\,\cdots\, x_nB]vec(G).$$ Then, Hilbert-Schmidt norm of T equals $\|x^T\otimes B\|_{HS}$.

You can find related results searching for "[(x^T\otimes B)](https://www.searchonmath.com/result/?q=%5C%28x%5ET%5Cotimes%20B%5C%29%20) " on SearchOnMath.